# Is this junit test even necessary?

Tags: java, junit

My testing experience is mostly with Ruby's Rspec. And I recently tried to write a Java jUnit test. And here is an example. Then I started to wonder if this test is even necessary. Since `properties()` will either return a `Properties` or `null` - based on the method signature. So if I want to test the method, all I should do is to test if the return value is not null.

```
public class HelperTest  {
@Test
public void testProperties() {
       assertThat(Helper.properties(), instanceOf(Properties.class));
    }
}


public class Helper {
   public static Properties properties() {
            // ... some code to init properties ...
           return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with `assertNotNull(...)`?

Comment: ... or `assertThat(Helper.properties()).isNotNull()`?

Comment: A test which never fails, just gives a false sense of security.

Comment: Hi all, I've created a answer based on your comments. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments. Let me try to answer my  question based on the comments.

This is the new test:

```
public void testProperties() {
    assertThat(Helper.properties(), is(notNullValue()));
}
```

I will simply test to make sure the method is not returning a null value. If the method is returning a non-null value, it will be an instance of a Properties. Which means it is unnecessary to test if the method returns an instance of a Properties.

Comment: But you said it could return a null as well, depending on the signature. It'll definitely return a Properties if it returns a non-null- it has to, by definition.

Comment: But you said it could return a null as well, depending on the signature. It'll definitely return a Properties if it returns a non-null- it has to, by definition.

Comment: Hey @DaveNewton  1) Since the assertion expects the method to return a non-null value 2) And the signature explicitly expects a Properties to be returned. Which means that a non-null value will definitely be a Properties.    Can I say that it is sufficient for test that the method returns a non null value, since non null value will definitely be a Properties. Appreciate if you have any more opinions on this!